# Mono.Zeroconf service port is always set to 0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mono, bonjour, zeroconf

I am trying to use [Mono.ZeroConf](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/monozeroconf/#how-to-use-it) for service discovery. I can discover services normally, but port of every service is always set to 0 instead of actual value.

I am using `.NET 4`, and `ZeroConf 0.9.0`, here is my code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    serviceBrowser = new ServiceBrowser();
    serviceBrowser.ServiceAdded += ServiceAdded;
    serviceBrowser.Browse(0, AddressProtocol.Any, "_http._tcp.", "local");
}

private void ServiceAdded(object o, ServiceBrowseEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("*** Found name = '{0}', type = '{1}', domain = '{2}'",
    args.Service.Name,
    args.Service.RegType,
    args.Service.ReplyDomain);
    args.Service.Resolved += ServiceResolver;

    if (args.Service.Name.Equals("MyService") && 
        args.Service.RegType.Equals("_http._tcp."))
    {
        args.Service.Resolve();
    }
}

private void ServiceResolver(object o, ServiceResolvedEventArgs args)
{
    IResolvableService service = o as IResolvableService;
    Console.Write("*** Resolved name = '{0}', host ip = '{1}', hostname = {2}, 
    port = '{3}', " + "interface = '{4}', address type = '{5}'",
    service.FullName, service.HostEntry.AddressList[0],
    service.HostEntry.HostName, service.Port,
    service.NetworkInterface, service.AddressProtocol);
}
```

When I use [MZClient](https://github.com/mono/Mono.Zeroconf/blob/master/src/MZClient/ZeroconfClient.cs) 0.8.0 to discover services all ports values are as expected, but when I use 0.9.0, same thing happens.

How can I get proper port value? Is it due to some bug in version 0.9.0, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Mono.Zeroconf, which is fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/mono/Mono.Zeroconf/pull/4).

You'll need to build the library yourself until the pull request is accepted and the Nuget package is published again.